# while creating new angular application getting error - Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to create a new angular app using the node command prompt. but while creating the new angular application its throwing error

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
>
> throw err;
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'

**Node JS Version : v11.11.0 - Angular-cli Version : 6.7.0**

```
D:\Angular Project>ng new testapp
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental\jobs\create-job-handler.js:11:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
```

Comment: check  if node is installed properly . try `npm cache clean --force` and see. If still not working then reinstall angular cli

Answer (score -2):

Install the stable version of your node `10.15.3`.

Delete the `package-lock.json` & the folder `node_modules` after run `npm install`